# SSH to a server from Jenkins and run shell commands

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

All,

I am trying to run multiple shell commands on a remote server through Jenkins

I have tried the below code with Execute Shell, plugin 
sudo su

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ec2-user/card.pem ec2-user@10.205.75.204 cat /home/ec2-user/testfile.txt
```

the problem with this is i can only run one command , for more than 1 I need to run 
sudo su

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ec2-user/card.pem ec2-user@10.205.75.204 cat /home/ec2-user/testfile.txt 
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ec2-user/card.pem ec2-user@10.205.75.204 rm -rf /home/ec2-user/testfile.txt
```

how can we achieve running mutiple commands like this?

Answer (score 1):

Hey @ Siraj Syed check following example:

```
String commandToRun = 'cat /home/ec2-user/testfile.txt; rm -rf /home/ec2-user/testfile.txt'

// pipeline step
sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ec2-user/card.pem ec2-user@10.205.75.204 /bin/bash -c '\"${commandToRun}\"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ec2-user/card.pem ec2-user@10.205.75.204 "cat /home/ec2-user/testfile.txt; rm -rf /home/ec2-user/testfile.txt"
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it will not work for pipeline @Peter McNab, second command will run on jenkins not on remote host.